# XeLaTeX, bidi, hyperref, longtable conflict

Tags: xetex, hyperref, longtable, incompatibility, bidi

Take a look at this XeLaTeX file:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bidi}

\begin{document}
  \begin{longtable}{l}
    x
  \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

When I try to compile this, I get this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@currentHref 

l.10   \end{longtable}
```

If I remove either `hyperref` or `bidi` from the list of packages, everything works nicely. Unfortunately, I need both of these packages.

What can I do?

**EDIT: Added \listfiles**

The `\listfiles` command gives this list:

```
 *File List*
       x.tex
  memoir.cls    2013/05/30 v3.7b configurable book, report, article document class
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
  ifetex.sty    2011/12/15 v1.2 ifetex
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
   mem10.clo    2008/01/30 v0.3 memoir class 10pt size option
mempatch.sty    2009/07/24 v6.0f Patches for memoir class v1.6180339
longtable.sty    2004/02/01 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
memhfixc.sty    2013/05/30 v1.17 nameref/hyperref package fixes for memoir class
  hxetex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for XeTeX
   puenc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
stringenc.sty    2011/12/02 v1.10 Convert strings between diff. encodings (HO)
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
    bidi.sty    2014/02/05 v14.6 Bidirectional typesetting in plain TeX and LaTeX
   iftex.sty    2013/04/04 v0.2 Provides if(tex) conditional for PDFTeX, XeTeX,
 and LuaTeX
biditools.sty    2013/04/10 v0.2 Programming tools for bidi package
zref-abspage.sty    2012/04/04 v2.24 Module abspage for zref (HO)
zref-base.sty    2012/04/04 v2.24 Module base for zref (HO)
latex-xetex-bidi.def    2013/10/10 v1.1.5 bidi adaptations for `latex.ltx' for XeTeX engine
footnote-xetex-bidi.def    2013/04/26 v0.8 bidi footnote macros for XeTeX engine
memoir-xetex-bidi.def    2010/07/25 v0.5 bidi adaptations for memoir class for XeTeX engine
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
   xetex.def    2013/04/29 v0.96 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (RRM/JK) 
graphicx-xetex-bidi.def    2012/01/01 v0.4 bidi adaptations for graphicx package for XeTeX engine
hyperref-xetex-bidi.def    2013/04/08 v0.7 bidi adaptations for hyperref package for XeTeX engine
array-xetex-bidi.def    2010/08/01 v0.2b bidi adaptations for array package for XeTeX engine
longtable-xetex-bidi.def    2013/04/01 v0.3 bidi adaptations for longtable package for XeTeX engine
loadingorder-xetex-bidi.def    2013/05/22 v0.95 making sure that bidi is the last package loaded
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
       x.out
       x.out
se-ascii-print.def    2011/12/02 v1.10 stringenc: Printable ASCII characters
 ***********
```

Comment: `bidi` must be loaded after `hyperref`. It complains if that is not the case.

Comment: ok then, I wasn't quite sure. sorry for that.

Comment: It runs without error for me in a tl2014 updated yesterday can you add `\listfiles` to your preamble and post the resulting list from the log?

Comment: I have added the `\listfiles` list to my original post.

Comment: Your `keyval`, `longtable` and `graphicx` package versions are really outdated

Comment: many of your packages are old, but I would guess the crucial difference is that in a current texlive bidi is `Package: bidi 2015/02/17` yours is a year older. You should at least update bidi if not your whole tex distribution.

Comment: I was afraid of that, David. My installation is just what comes with Ubuntu. So it seems Ubuntu doesn't do a good job of keeping track of LaTeX development. Anyway, I tried running `tlmgr update --list` and it said "no updates available". So I guess I'll have to install TeX live from scratch. Do I have any other choice? (My tlmgr says it's TeX live 2013.)

Comment: You always have the option of just getting bidi from ctan and unpacking it in a local directory. there is nothing magical about latex package installs, it is just a matter of putting some tex files where latex can find them.

Comment: yes tlmgr does not do in place edits after the next years comes out, you could get tl2014, but tl2015 will be along in a few months (I don't know exactly, usually around May I think)

Comment: Okay, I did a `tlmgr install bidi` and it installed the latest version locally. Now my XeLaTeX file compiles without error! The problem is solved! David, if you'd turn you comment into an answer, I'll acknowledge it as the answer to this question. Thank you.

Comment: If you use an `@` to ping me I'd have seen your comment, it was just lucky I was flicking through the "unanswered" list and came back here:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the crucial difference is that in a current texlive `bidi` is

```
Package: bidi 2015/02/17
```

yours is a year older. You should at least update `bidi`, it apparently has fixes to address this issue.